# PHP get_headers() Returns Nothing on Remote Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a Wordpress plugin that I am building in which I use the PHP get_headers() function to get the headers of a remote URL. Problem is that sometimes get_headers() returns nothing at all. I have tested the plugin locally and it always gets something when the function is called, but on some of my sites it returns nothing after I install the plugin on the remote host.

Is it possible for a conflict with another plugin to render get_headers() unavailable for my plugin?

The code I use is quite basic

```
$headers = get_headers($sourceurl,1);
            $statuscode = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
            if ($statuscode == 404)
            { ... }
```

When I noticed nothing for the error code I tried to echo all the headers like so

```
foreach($headers as $header)
                    {
                        echo $header;
                    }
```

That also returns nothing.

The sites whose URLs are being checked are sites I own. There is nothing on them that should block a curl or get_headers() request from any source.

Comment: which server is it Apache or Nginx ?

Comment: Apache server, I also noticed that all the domains that it is not working on are hosted in subdirectories of the sites that are working just fine. They were setup simply by adding additional domains to accounts in cPanel that have their own directory within the domain that was originally used to create the account.